# Cannot see local variables when opening an App Services Debug Snapshot

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I just spent some time configuring a test .NET Core 2 Web App with Debug Snapshots according to [this doc from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger)

I works quite well and I am able to open the snapshot through the portal, however it displays this error for all the local variables:

"Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away."

I already installed the latest Application Insights site extension into the Web App, restarted the App (just in case) and I can see it in the Extensions panel, however I still cannot see the vars through the portal - what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when deploying from Visual Studio to Azure App Service.  Debug was selected in the dropdown on the menu bar, so I was confused.

The issue was that the Publish screen in Visual Studio contains a setting called "Configuration" which was set to Release.  I clicked "Configure" and set it to Debug.  Problem was solved.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the comment. I will give it a try